# Error when trying to load Android 1.6 virtual device from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, virtual-machine

I am self leaning Java rookie

and I doth (as in Shakespeare 'Doth')received the following error message back when trying to start the Android 1.6 VM( The reason I am using Android 1.6 and not later versions is that it takes less time to load on my slow P.C!) from Eclipse:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/ref/FinalReference
```

I have successfully started Android 1.6 VM from the AVD manager so the VM software appears to be O.K.

and the source code appears to be o.k - and is the default code that should initialize the VM:

```
package com.leigh.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Any Help would would be appreciated.

Comment: are other apps working fine? or this is ur 1st app?

Comment: Maybe don't have the word namespace in your package name? **random guess**

Comment: I presume I am not using any Jdk version at the moment as I have not written any code, I simply started a new Android Project using Android 1.6 VM. - But for you information I have JDK1.7.0_03 compiler installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for you information I have JDK1.7.0_03 compiler installed

The android tools, such as the emulator, [depend on a JDK 6 (1.6.x) installation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html). They won't run properly with a JDK 7 installation (1.7.x). [Install JDK 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-downloads-1637591.html) instead and try again.

Comment: Hi, o.k I have installed jdk 1.6 version. so how do I tell Eclipse to start using this instead of version 1.7???

Comment: that seems to of done the trick, I have now successfully installed and run a test HelloWorld program on the Android emulator - yes! (it was not easy , but I got there in the end with all coders help, thank you)

Comment: For anyone that wants to know - you must uninstall the previous jdk1.7x version and then install version 1.6 for this to work.

Comment: Also I recommend: following the HelloWorld install instruction supplied  by Android developers site. This will guidw

Comment: Also note: Always uninstall an applcation from the emulator before installing another one with the same name!