# Error when trying to initialize Android 1.6 Emulator from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, initialization

I am a self learning Java bigginner.

Reference an similar earlier question I posed:

[Earlier Question regarding error loading Android VD from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050576/error-when-trying-to-load-android-1-6-virtual-device-from-eclipse)

After posing the previous similar question It was recommended by a @alextsc that I change my installed jdk version from  JDK1.7.0_03  to version jdk 6 as the Android tools only work with version jdk 6 (1.6)

This I have done and then changed the project settings:
I checked that the default compliance setting was 1.6 in the Java compiler under project settings
and I changed the Run configuration for the project - making sure that the jre was set to version jre6
Plus I changed the windows environment variables  to ...java\jdk1.6.0_04

hoping this would allow my project to compile - but it has not!

Now my questions are:

how do I get the project to compile with jdk 1.6?

and what else do I need to configure?

- at the end of the day I just want to install a HelloWorld test program on to Android 1.6 Emulator - run from Eclipse IDE environment.

I did try again to run the default code as follows:

```
package com.leigh.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I have successfully started Android 1.6 VM from the AVD manager so the VM software appears to be O.K.

and the source code appears to be o.k - and is the default code that should initialize the VM:
and this time I received a different error message back, as follows:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3494), pid=5904, tid=3496
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\leighman\workspace\HelloWorld\hs_err_pid5904.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

and the log file is here:

> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0x018a9c00):  JavaThread "Unknown thread"
>   [_thread_in_vm, id=3516, stack(0x00350000,0x003a0000)]
>
> Stack: [0x00350000,0x003a0000],  sp=0x0039f86c,  free space=318k
>   Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code,
>   C=native code) V  [jvm.dll+0x1335ba] V  [jvm.dll+0x12e56b] V 
>   [jvm.dll+0x1639e] V  [jvm.dll+0x17bdf] V  [jvm.dll+0x26cc5] V 
>   [jvm.dll+0x27506] V  [jvm.dll+0x278b5] V  [jvm.dll+0x27949] V 
>   [jvm.dll+0x27a0c] V  [jvm.dll+0x27a8a] V  [jvm.dll+0x27b6d] V 
>   [jvm.dll+0x27e39] V  [jvm.dll+0x6c383] V  [jvm.dll+0x6c75c] V 
>   [jvm.dll+0xf9b4c] V  [jvm.dll+0x11848b] V  [jvm.dll+0x9eb60] C 
>   [javaw.exe+0x1657] C  [javaw.exe+0x1e2c] C  [javaw.exe+0x8614] C 
>   [kernel32.dll+0x4ed6c]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12 C 
>   [ntdll.dll+0x6377b]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xef C 
>   [ntdll.dll+0x6374e]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0xc2
>
> ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
>
> Java Threads: ( => current thread )
>
> Other Threads:
>
> =>0x018a9c00 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=3516, stack(0x00350000,0x003a0000)]
>
> VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)
>
> VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None
>
> Dynamic libraries: 0x00400000 - 0x00424000    C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe 0x77bf0000 - 0x77d2c000
>     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 0x77410000 - 0x774e4000
>     C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll 0x75f20000 - 0x75f6a000
>     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 0x76220000 - 0x762c0000
>     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll 0x776c0000 - 0x7776c000
>     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll 0x76370000 - 0x76389000
>     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll 0x760a0000 - 0x76141000
>     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll 0x775f0000 - 0x776b9000
>     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll 0x77340000 - 0x7738e000
>     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll 0x77d80000 - 0x77d8a000
>     C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll 0x774f0000 - 0x7758d000
>     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll 0x77390000 - 0x773af000
>     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL 0x76150000 - 0x7621c000
>     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll 0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll 0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll 0x73fb0000 - 0x73fe2000
>     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll 0x75c80000 - 0x75ccc000
>     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll 0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll 0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000    C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll 0x6d370000 - 0x6d399000  C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\jdwp.dll 0x6d690000 - 0x6d696000  C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\npt.dll 0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll 0x76090000 - 0x76095000
>     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
>
> VM Arguments: jvm_args:
>   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:1554 -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-4\android.jar 
>   java_command: com.leigh.namespace.HelloWorldActivity Launcher Type:
>   SUN_STANDARD
>
> Environment Variables: CLASSPATH=.;.. PATH=C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Program
>   Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Profram
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Eclipse\eclipse; USERNAME=leighman
>   OS=Windows_NT PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 28 Stepping 10,
>   GenuineIntel
>
> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
>
> OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1
>
> CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 28
>   stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, ht
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical 1037616k(107780k free), swap
>   2086192k(357112k free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06) for windows-x86 JRE
>   (1.6.0_27-b07), built on Jul 19 2011 01:04:42 by "java_re" with MS
>   VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)
>
> time: Sun Jun 17 12:41:45 2012 elapsed time: 0 seconds

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: C:\profram files\ doesn:t seem to be a valid folder (bottom of PROCESS in the log)

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain further -@azulflame?

Comment: Your java \bin folder needs to be re-added. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm asking for IDE's. It was a typo. Eclipse, Netbeans, Jcreator, etc (I'm on my phone, and the question is a MASSIVE wall of text)

Comment: I have just looked in the directory tree: and I find that there is a bin folder in the jdk1.6.0_04 folder but not the java folder - so are you saying there should be a bin folder in the java folder?

Comment: You're still using 1.7, not 1.6

Comment: I am using Eclipse Indigo version

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: Uninstall & reinstall java, and see if that helps

Comment: O.k, thanks @azulflame I will try this and report back - but surely there must be a simple way of telling Eclipse to use jdk1.6 - after all I have installed it!

Comment: I don't use eclipse, save for modding MC, so I'm not the best troubleshooter. Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks @azulflame - that seems to of done the trick, I have now successfully installed and run a test HelloWorld program on the Android emulator - yes! (it was not easy , but I got there in the end with all coders help, thank you) . If you like I can put your answer in as a Answer and then I can give you marks and a tick...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling java (uninstalling first, of course)